# How to reduce number of lines of code in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

Our angular 5 application file keeps on growing, as our app is a SPA with dynamic components. We use layout as a main component and render other components on main. Thereby most of the logic falls on the main component and main component.ts occupies around 1460 lines. We've moved utility methods to utility but still we have 1460 lines.

Share your thoughts on here.

Comment: Why are 1400 lines a problem? But apart from that, your app seems to lack some structure if you do everything in main.

Comment: Check few angular admin project structure to understand how angular app flow should be and change your app accordingly. Your app should be splitted in to different modules and small components.

Answer (score 3):

Where A is your main component, you are doing this:

A --> B

So all the logic for the callback handlers in component B are in component A, muddying the waters for A. (Obviously there will be C, D, E, etc whose callback logic is also in A).

You should be doing this:

A --> B --> C

Here C is responsible for the main logic for whatever C does and B handles the callback events. A is kept clean.

(You may develop B and C together or C may be a reusable or a library component)

This is a recognised pattern in Angular but one that is ignored by new developers. This pattern ensures separation of concerns.

Inter component communication is generally achieved through a global store solution such as ngrx or via Subject based services (although @Input @Output pattern is also useful at times too).

ngrx: https://github.com/ngrx/platform (great tutorials on Udemy)

Subject based services: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service (not restricted to parent-child)

This article might be helpful: https://blog.angulartraining.com/component-architecture-with-angular-6f7bc9165443?__s=nrn5hrwjji1wznrbpids

Also, worth mentioning, components exist for 1 of 2 reasons:

(1) code organisation - to reduce the amount of code / complexity of a parent component.

(2) re-use

Here you need to focus on (1) and modularising your app better.